# A program doesn't work when invoked through a symbolic link

Tags: symlink, executable

I have an executable `paraview` in the directory `~/software/Para/bin/` and
I want to create a soft link in my home directory. I have tried like this but could not succeed.

```
sudo ln -s ~/software/Para/bin/paraview para123;
```

A soft link was created with this command but its not running my application. The same was happened for

```
sudo ln -s ./software/Para/bin/paraview para123
```

and also tried this

```
 ln -s "/home/niyaa/software/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/bin/paraview" para123
```

The error is

```
Error converting runtime path entry "./../lib/paraview-4.3" to real path: No such file or directory
```

Comment: All approaches should work and if you replace paraview with a simple executable mock such as a scriptfile containing `echo hello world` you should see they do work. The problem must be somewhere else. What errors does it give? What is `$?` after you run the `./para123` link from `$HOME`?

Comment: Error converting runtime path entry "./../lib/paraview-4.3" to real path: No such file or directory

Comment: thanks i make bash script in my home folder its start working.. now i am curious about the soft link that how to done it that way.

Comment: There's your problem right there. Paraview is trying to load a library and it's resolving the library's path relative to the executable. The problem is, it looks liek `./para123` is the executable now, ant there's no `./../lib/paraview-4-3` relative to it. If you don't want to modify the paraview package, what you might want to do is forget about symlinks for now and instead use a simple script that runs the original `paraview` executable.

Comment: LOL. I see you solved it that way a couple of seconds before I suggested it.  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

With the information in the comments to the question, one of the following may be an adequate solution.

1. Use an alias:

   ```
   alias para123="$HOME/software/Para/bin/paraview"
   ```
2. Use a shell function:

   ```
   para123 () { "$HOME/software/Para/bin/paraview" "$@"; }
   ```
3. Use a shell script (called `para123`):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   "$HOME/software/Para/bin/paraview" "$@"
   ```

Comment: Option 2 coded in a .bashrc file worked well for me. I used the formulation `parawhat () { <path to paraview executable> "$@" &> /dev/null & }` to suppress stdout and sterr streams and send the job to the background.